# Why are questions sorted by the votes they received?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, sorting, question-lists

I totally agree when answer are sorted according their rating on the result page, no question about the reason here. Although when I'm viewing my profile page I would like to see my recent questions first. It would allow me to easily see if there is any new answer.

It would be nice (as people have said below) to have that option "stick" so somebody could persist a different sort order.

(Also it would be nice if the page wouldn't scroll up. There is no reason it should behave in this manner.)

Comment: If this is a question about changing the default behaviour, rephrase it! If you want that your choice is "remembered" (as an personal option) rephrase it, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the ordering. Click *recent* on the right side, same level as *Questions*.

[alt text http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/9758/recentquestions.jpg](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/9758/recentquestions.jpg)

Comment: Image needs more hand-drawniness

Comment: I figured it out :). The question is actually a propousal too.

Comment: @random: even more?

Comment: I don't think this setting "sticks" though

Comment: Just checked and it doesn't remember the setting between page views (unlike the ordering on answers to questions).

Comment: @ChrisF: making it an option that *sticks*, would be a feature request indeed.

Comment: @John Smithers: I wasn't actually making a request - just pointing out current behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

You have multiple ways of sorting the answers, but the traditional idea is that you want all the best answers to "bubble up" to the top. This is not exactly your traditional forum software where you expect to see something chronologically. This is a Q&A software where you expect to see questions and then the best answers.

Comment: I was actually meaning profile page :). I getting stackoverflow and enjoying it every singel day :))

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if you can't answer "who cares what order the answers were posted?" then you are **not *getting* Stack Overflow**.

Stack Overflow is a "Question & Answer" forum, not a tradition "Discussion" forum.

**The Traditional Discussion Forum**

Messages are threaded; each message is part of a larger discussion which flows together to form an on-going conversation about the original topic. Most-recent ordering of posts makes sense here.

**Stack Overflow**

The primary purpose is to quickly get an answer to a question; a specific question with a specific answer. Each answer is written to be *atomic*; that is, each answer should stand on its own to best address the question asked. Each post is reviewed and voted on by the community-of-experts for its merits. The most-voted-on answers float to the top. Community members can add to or correct information in posts through a Wiki-style contribution. Finally, the original poster selects the question that best solves their problem.

The very nature of ordering posts by votes **inhibits long, drawn out discussions. That is by design.**

You can select to order posts by most "recent" posts but that is better used to see the most recent contribution to a question you have been following for awhile. Sort-by-most-votes is the intended way the system was designed to be used.

Comment: +1 Excellent. This answer is FAQ worthy.